# TYPO3 v12 - Localization is not working with xlf files

Tags: typo3

I am trying to get the translation to work in Typo3 12.1.3.

I build a simple site package following the [Sitepackage Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/main/en-us/).

I added some locallang files:
**locallang.xlf**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf" date="2011-10-17T20:22:32Z" product-name="site_package">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="test" resname="test">
                <source>Test (EN)</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

**de.locallang.xlf**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" target-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf" date="2011-10-17T20:22:32Z" product-name="site_package" >
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="test" resname="test" approved="yes">
                <source>Test (EN)</source>
                <target>Test (DE)</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Created some template:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Main">

  <main role="main">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <f:translate key="LLL:EXT:site_package/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:test"/>
          <f:translate key="test" extensionName="site_package"/>

            <f:for each="{mainContent}" as="contentElement">
                <f:cObject
                    typoscriptObjectPath="tt_content.{contentElement.data.CType}"
                    data="{contentElement.data}"
                    table="tt_content"
                />
            </f:for>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>

</f:section>
```

And added a site configuration:

```
base: /
languages:
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-us
    direction: ltr
    flag: us
    websiteTitle: ''
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: de
    languageId: 1
rootPageId: 1
websiteTitle: ''
```

Afterwards I created a site, added some content and translated it to German in the backend.

**Problem:**
The content elements are presented in the selected language in the frontend.
If I switch it, they are presented in the matching language.

The text from the locallang file stays in the default language.
If I switch the language, they are not presented in the right language. They stay in English.

What am I doning wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 still had a bug.
The patch https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/78325 solved the problem for me (this patch is not even included in v12.3)

Comment: I have applied it manually and it has worked for me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

can you check again with TYPO3 v12.2.0? This might solve these problems...

Comment: Hi Benni,
thanks for your fast reply.

Changes sources to v12.2.0. 
The error remains.

Comment: @JanW. could you solve the problem in between? For me it is even given in TYPO3 v12.3.0

Comment: I have the same error in TYPO3 v12.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with TYPO3 v12.2 like the threadstarter. I'm using DDEV locally and the main content of the page is German and created a page translation to English. The output still remains in English.

The section for languages in the **config.yaml** file in my site configuration:

```
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.utf8
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: 'Meine Webseite'
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    flag: de
    languageId: 0
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.utf8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: 'My website'
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: en-us-gb
    languageId: 1
```

The German translation file **de.locallang.xlf** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="EXT:custompackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf" date="2020-10-18T18:20:51Z" product-name="custompackage" target-language="de">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <!-- Topbar -->
            <trans-unit id="topbar.book-appointment" resName="topbar.book-appointment" approved="yes">
                <target state="translated">Termin online buchen</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

The English (default) translation file **locallang.xlf** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="EXT:custompackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf" date="2020-10-18T18:20:51Z" product-name="custompackage">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <!-- Topbar -->
            <trans-unit id="topbar.book-appointment">
                <source>Book appointment</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Fluid template, first with German default label, second without:

```
<f:translate extensionName="custompackage" id="topbar.book-appointment">Termin online buchen</f:translate>
```

```
<f:translate extensionName="custompackage" id="topbar.book-appointment"/>
```

The second variant returns the English label by default.

I also noticed changing the **user backend language** affects the frontend localization output. If German was set up as a user backend language, German labels appear in the frontend and with English the other way. That's a strange behavior. Any idea why this happens?

What's the right way to set up translations for own composer extensions?
Do they belong to `var/labels/{language}/{customExtension}` or the regular way to `packages/{customExtension}/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf`? The [localization documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Localization/ManagingTranslations.html) for TYPO3 v12 (main) shows the regular way.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems like you both with `TYPO3 12.2.0`.
But I've made a mistake with my folder name. I created a folder named "Languages", but it has to be "Language".

So maybe check your convensions ... now the Localisation works fine with TYPO3 12. You don't need a second Website Language to show your data in different languages. You only need special files, like `locallang.xlf` for english and `de.locallang.xlf` for german.

[image: Folder name Language]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. It seems that it's necessary to have the according language pack installed in v12.

Installing the according language pack fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 v12.4.0 (published today) contains the bugfix, it is recommended to update to this version to also solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem but in my case the language iso code i was using is not any more in the list of default language codes in Locales class of typo3. here is the default list.

```
  $languages = [
    'default' => 'English',
    'af' => 'Afrikaans',
    'ar' => 'Arabic',
    'bs' => 'Bosnian',
    'bg' => 'Bulgarian',
    'ca' => 'Catalan',
    'ch' => 'Chinese (Simple)',
    'cs' => 'Czech',
    'cy' => 'Welsh',
    'da' => 'Danish',
    'de' => 'German',
    'el' => 'Greek',
    'eo' => 'Esperanto',
    'es' => 'Spanish',
    'et' => 'Estonian',
    'eu' => 'Basque',
    'fa' => 'Persian',
    'fi' => 'Finnish',
    'fo' => 'Faroese',
    'fr' => 'French',
    'fr_CA' => 'French (Canada)',
    'gl' => 'Galician',
    'he' => 'Hebrew',
    'hi' => 'Hindi',
    'hr' => 'Croatian',
    'hu' => 'Hungarian',
    'is' => 'Icelandic',
    'it' => 'Italian',
    'ja' => 'Japanese',
    'ka' => 'Georgian',
    'kl' => 'Greenlandic',
    'km' => 'Khmer',
    'ko' => 'Korean',
    'lb' => 'Luxembourgish',
    'lt' => 'Lithuanian',
    'lv' => 'Latvian',
    'mi' => 'Maori',
    'mk' => 'Macedonian',
    'ms' => 'Malay',
    'nl' => 'Dutch',
    'no' => 'Norwegian',
    'pl' => 'Polish',
    'pt' => 'Portuguese',
    'pt_BR' => 'Brazilian Portuguese',
    'ro' => 'Romanian',
    'ru' => 'Russian',
    'rw' => 'Kinyarwanda',
    'sk' => 'Slovak',
    'sl' => 'Slovenian',
    'sn' => 'Shona (Bantu)',
    'sq' => 'Albanian',
    'sr' => 'Serbian',
    'sv' => 'Swedish',
    'th' => 'Thai',
    'tr' => 'Turkish',
    'uk' => 'Ukrainian',
    'vi' => 'Vietnamese',
    'zh' => 'Chinese (Traditional)',
    'zh_CN' => 'Chinese (Simplified)',
    'zh_HK' => 'Chinese (Simplified Hong Kong)',
    'zh_Hans_CN' => 'Chinese (Simplified Han)',
];
```

but we can define locale that is missing here in settings.php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['localization']['locales']['user']

```
'SYS' => [
    'localization' => [
        'locales'  => [
            'user' => [
                'id' => 'Indonasian',
            ],
        ]
    ],
],
```